# Windows XP Embedded C++ TR1 - The procedure entry point ?_Xmem@tr1@std@@YAXXZ could not be located

Tags: c++, regex, windows-xp-embedded

I'm building a Windows app and recently included use of the std::tr1::regex functions.  Now when I go to run my app on XP embedded I get the above error.  How do I fix this?  App. used to work before I used the regex functions, which I really need to use.

Thank you,
Fred

Comment: Make sure the machine has the correct run-time installed -- the latest version for the particular version of VS you used.

Comment: I'm using VS 2008 express, how to I check the runtime?

Comment: You can get the installer/verifier/updater from [Microsoft's download page](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29).

Comment: I ran that package but still get the same error.  The regex is from the std::tr1 namespace, could that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Are you using Boost tr1? Where are you getting tr1 from? It's not part of VS2008, right?

Comment: I'm not sure where the tr1 implementation is coming from, it could be a part of VS2008, not sure how to check.

Comment: tr1 was not part of initial VS2008 release, but was added as part of Feature Pack.  That feature pack also included updated versions of the redistributable dll files.  You probably have the Feature Pack on your dev system, but not the correct runtime dll's on the XP embedded.

Comment: ... and the Feature Pack was rolled into VS 2008 SP1. I'm not experienced with XP Embedded, but SO has some answers involving copying dlls in you app folder. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7398038/900626

Answer (score 0):

You need to download 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package' known as vcredist. It is found over [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582)